# As a freelance iOS developer, how would you go about taking royalties on your app from your client?

Tags: ios, itunes

I have just finished an iOS app for a client who wishes to charge for it, but he'd like me to do periodic updates and the like after I upload it to iTunes. I have already received the payment for the development of the app. As payment for periodic updates however, I was going to work on a percentage of what he is selling the app for. This is my first freelance for pay job and I'm not sure about the protocol and how I would go about receiving payment.

How would I know how much money he was receiving from the app without asking for the monthly financial records or just trusting that he was telling me the correct amount?

I haven't seen any questions regarding the business side of iOS app production so if this question is not appropriate for SO please let me know and possibly direct me to a more directed forum for this topic. I just have confidence that there must be several experienced freelance developers who could possibly help me not make beginner mistakes with clients.

Cheers

Comment: It's not in topic for SO, you're right. Not sure where it does go though, I'm not familiar with many of the other sites.

Comment: This is an issue you will face in business. You either need to trust your partner (essentially what your client will become if you are sharing revenue) or things will end up in court. I'd advise against making a client a partner unless you are going to take a stake in the company (shares/% ownership). Charge him per hour for updates. Asking for a percentage of sales is going to be difficult to enforce unless you are prepared to take legal action in which case you will lose your client even if you "win".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mike Z, thats a good idea.